# how to patch selector and label service name of deployment.yaml in kustomization.yaml

Tags: github, kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

**My Setup:** `GitHub`(Build Pipeline) + `Kustomize` + `Kubernetes`

**Kustomize structure:**

--base
----deployment.yaml
----service.yaml
----kustomizationn.yaml
--env-country1
----kustomizationn.yaml
--env-country2
----kustomizationn.yaml

**Issue:**
I am trying to patch the `spec.selector.matchLabels.service` and `spec.template.metadata.labels.service` values present in the `deployment.yaml` in the base.

**what I tried:**

1. I tried to use `patch` like below:

   ```
   patches:
   - patch: |-
    - op: replace
     path: /metadata/name
     value: <serviceName>-<country>
    - op: replace
     path: /spec/selector/matchLabels/service
     value: <serviceName>-<country>
    - op: replace
     path: /spec/template/metadata/labels/service
     value: <serviceName>-<country>  
    target:
    kind: Deployment
   ```

**Issue:** these are immutable entities, hence can't be patched.

I also tried to research but was not able to find any related documentation with examples.

**PS:** I am not using helm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wanted to [replicate your issue so I can debug it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but there is some information missing. Could you please share example deployment, services, kustomization (from base + env-country directories) yamls files? Which commands did you run and from which directories? Please also share information about used kustmize version (`kustomize version` command).